# Codeigniter foreach whithout $id

Tags: php, codeigniter

how i can sort some informations without $id? My problem is, that i ca read all teams and users. but how i can sort this?
So that i get a team and the players from this team in one box. WIth my code i have all users in all boxes.

Can i foreach in a foreach?

view what i try:

```
<?php foreach ($teams as $item): ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <?php echo $item->teamname ?>
        </div>


   <?php foreach ($users as $item): ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <?php echo $item->username ?>
        </div>
   <?php endforeach ?>


<?php endforeach ?>
```

This is my database

table users

```
user_id username team_id

   1     paul      1
   2     tom       2
   3     brad      1
   4     pim       2
```

table team

```
team_id   teamname

  1         team1
  2         team1
```

Now i have a subside like domaincom/teams
And i want on this side

team 1 : paul, brad
team 2 : tom, pim

controller:

```
    <?php

    class Teams extends CI_Controller {

    public $layout = 'full';
    public $module = 'teams';
    public $model = 'Teams_model';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model($this->model);
        $this->_primary_key = $this->{$this->model}->_primary_keys[0];
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['teams'] = $this->{$this->model}->get_teams();
        $data['users'] = $this->{$this->model}->get_users();
        $data['teamsWithUsers'] = $this->{$this->model}->get_users_by_team();

        $data['items'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
        $this->load->view($this->module, $data);
    }
}
```

this is my model

```
 <?php

    class Teams_model extends CI_model
{
    public $_table = 'teams';
    public $_primary_keys = array('teams_id');

    function get_teams()
    {
        return $this->db->get('teams')->result();
    }

    function get_users()
    {
        return $this->db->get('users')->result();
    }

    function get_users_by_team($teamID = null)
    {           
        $this->db->select('u.user_id, u.username, u.team_id, t.teamname');
        $this->db->from('users AS u');
        $this->db->join('teams AS t', 't.team_id = u.team_id');
        if ($teamID != '') {
            $this->db->where('t.team_id', $teamID);
        }
        $this->db->order_by('t.teamname', 'ASC');
        $this->db->order_by('u.username', 'ASC');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

What i looking for is this view sample

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about that?

your controller

```
public function index()
{
    $data['teams'] = $this->{$this->model}->get_teams();
    $data['users'] = $this->{$this->model}->get_users();

    $arrUsersPerTeam = [];

    foreach($data['users'] AS $objUser)
    {
        $arrUsersPerTeam[$objUser->team_id][] = $objUser;
    }

    $data['arrUsersPerTeam'] = $arrUsersPerTeam;

    $data['items'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
    $this->load->view($this->module, $data);
}
```

and your view

```
<?php 
foreach ($teams as $item): 
?>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <?php echo $item->teamname ?>
    </div>
   <?php 
    if (isset($arrUsersPerTeam[$item->team_id]))    :
        foreach ($arrUsersPerTeam[$item->team_id] as $objUser): 
    ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <?php echo $objUser->username ?>
        </div>
    <?php 
        endforeach; 
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a single join query to get your results make sure results are ordered by team

```
/**model*/

function some func(){

    $this->db->select( 'u.username, t.team_id, t.teamname' );
    $this->db->from( 'team AS t' );
    $this->db->join( 'users AS u', 't.team_id = u.team_id' );
    $this->db->order_by( 't.team_id', 'ASC' );
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

In your controller collect results returned by above method defined in your model and pass it to view.

In view there is no need for nested loop only single loop will do the job here like `$results` contains all the records then in view you can display your records as

```
/* view */
$parent = false;
$index = 1;
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <?php foreach ($results as $result){ ?>
         <?php if($parent !=$item->teamname ){ ?>
               <?php if($index !=1 ){ ?>
                  </div>
               <?php } ?>
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <h2><?php echo $result->teamname ?></h2>
         <?php } ?>

   <p><?php echo $result->username ?></p>
   <?php 
   $parent =$result->teamname;
   $index++;
   } ?>
</div> // To close the opened div
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things: you can pick out key from the foreach, that you can use later, second the "$item" is used 2 places where you might overwrite it by accident.

```
<?php foreach ($teams as $key => $team_item ): ?>
   <div class="col-xs-12">
     <?php echo $team_item->teamname ?>
   </div>
   <?php foreach ($users as $user_item): ?>
      <?php if($item->team_id == $key): ?>
         <div class="col-xs-12">
            <?php echo $user_item->username ?>
         </div>
        <?php endif ?>
   <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I'm not really sure if thats what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hey, thank you but its no working for me. I try that the users under the teamsname on view. That i have teamname > users with this team_id (1) > next teamname > users with this team_id maybe (3).